# Overriding Inline Help-Text/Getting Field Description from Apex

Tags: managed-package, package, helptext

I have a requirement . I need to be able to add descriptions to fields in our managed package which we can reference from Apex code and display on a VisualForce page.

Currently, Inline help-text which is added and packaged with fields on custom objects does not get added to an Org when updating the package. Instead, whatever help-text was previously present for those fields remains. **When we change the help-text and update our package and install it into an Org, we need to be able to override the help-text which was previously in the Org. Is there any way to do this?**

Comment: This makes sense otherwise the what functionality and label will be out of sync confusing end users. There is an idea created 8 years ago! https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IyWkAAK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share your pain at this behaviour; it would be entirely reasonable in my mind to make preserving or overwriting local changes an install time option.

Perhaps there are 3rd party tools that can help.

A "build your own" solution could be to write Apex code that goes through the fields in your custom objects via describe calls (in the org you package in) and uses [getInlineHelpText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getInlineHelpText) to build some JSON that holds the help text values for each field in each object. Include that JSON in your package as a static resource.

Then add a page (as a safer approach than trying to do this in an [InstallHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm)) that uses the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to update the help text in the orgs that are being upgraded taking the data from the JSON. Then tell you customers to run that page.